# compare words in two lists in python

Tags: python, list, compare, words

I would appreciate someone's help on this probably simple matter: I have a long list of words in the form `['word', 'another', 'word', 'and', 'yet', 'another']`. I want to compare these words to a list that I specify, thus looking for target words whether they are contained in the first list or not.

I would like to output which of my "search" words are contained in the first list and how many times they appear. I tried something like `list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))` - but it splits up the words and compares letters instead.

How can I write in a list of words to compare with the existing long list? And how can I output co-occurences and their frequencies? Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Can you post some code you tried. `set(['word', 'another'])` evaluates to `set(['word', 'another'])` and does not split up words to letters.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> lst = ['word', 'another', 'word', 'and', 'yet', 'another']
>>> search = ['word', 'and', 'but']
>>> [(w, lst.count(w)) for w in set(lst) if w in search]
[('and', 1), ('word', 2)]
```

This code basically iterates through the unique elements of `lst`, and if the element is in the `search` list, it adds the word, along with the number of occurences, to the resulting list.

Answer (score 4):

Preprocess your list of words with a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['word', 'another', 'word', 'and', 'yet', 'another']
c = Counter(a)
# c == Counter({'word': 2, 'another': 2, 'and': 1, 'yet': 1})
```

Now you can iterate over your new list of words and check whether they are contained within this Counter-dictionary and the value gives you their number of appearance in the original list:

```
words = ['word', 'no', 'another']

for w in words:
    print w, c.get(w, 0)
```

which prints:

```
word 2
no 0
another 2
```

or output it in a list:

```
[(w, c.get(w, 0)) for w in words]
# returns [('word', 2), ('no', 0), ('another', 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Both solutions seem to do fine, but my code allows for input of the sort [('S'), ('t'), ('o'), ('c'), ('k')] when i type Stock in sys.argv(2). How am I able to input more words to a comparable list as i execute the program? and with both your suggested solutions, it compares the letters rather then the entire word                               
conll=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
targetword=str(sys.argv[2])
vocab=[]

c = Counter(vocab)
print c

for w in targetword:
    print w, c.get(w, 0)
     
print [(w, vocab.count(w)) for w in set(vocab) if w in targetword]

print targetword